# Word Web Addin: How to track text changed event

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, cpu-word

I am starting developing a word web addin for Office 2019.
I suppose that I understand fundamentals for web addin.
Would like to hook text changed event on a document, but I couldn't figure out how it can be do.
I googled so much, however I couldn't any info even a hint. I wonder I cannot do that with Office JavaScript API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the text changed event is not supported in the Office JavaScript Library at this time. But it is a good idea. Please suggest it at [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/index.html). Be sure to tag it `office-addins-dev`.

Comment: Hi, Rick. Thank you for a suggestion. I would post a request to the MS-Q&A. Also I added a tag 'office-addins'.

Comment: I posted to the MS-Q&A, and added a tag 'office-addins-dev'.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/617426/word-web-addin-event-handler-for-text-changed.html